# CSS animated gradient not rendering

Tags: css

I am using https://www.gradient-animator.com/ to generate a CSS gradient animation which does not render..

The CSS:

```
.teste{
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000, #19408e, #15b9ca);
background-size: 600% 600%;

-webkit-animation: Gradnt 30s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: Gradnt 30s ease infinite;
-o-animation: Gradnt 30s ease infinite;
animation: Gradnt 30s ease infinite;

@-webkit-keyframes Gradnt {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%}
}
@-moz-keyframes Gradnt {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%}
}
@-o-keyframes Gradnt {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%}
}
@keyframes Gradnt { 
    0%{background-position:50% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%}
}

min-height:100%;
min-width:100%;
position:absolute;
}
```

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yoonma8v/

What's going on? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your keyframe out of the styling of your taste class. For example:

```
.teste{
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000, #19408e, #15b9ca);
background-size: 600% 600%;

-webkit-animation: Gradnt 30s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: Gradnt 30s ease infinite;
-o-animation: Gradnt 30s ease infinite;
animation: Gradnt 30s ease infinite;

min-height:100%;
min-width:100%;
position:absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Gradnt {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%}
}
@-moz-keyframes Gradnt {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%}
}
@-o-keyframes Gradnt {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%}
}
@keyframes Gradnt { 
    0%{background-position:50% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you got to use body and body:before
have a look in this article, might help [article](https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/animating-css-gradients-using-only-css-d2fd7671e759#.ipcy9hwbl)